# How can I export a blender file as an .stp?

Tags: export

My manufacturer requires that I supply the files that I've edited in Blender as .stp files but Blender does not offer this as an export option. I've tried exporting as .stl and then converting that with external software but they all seem to come back with errors. It's also a very detailed body scan, so I think that adds an additional layer of difficulty. Any advice very welcome! :)